# 2 foreign keys one create blade

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I think its an easy one but my brain is not trying to comprehend it. So the issue is I have a series table, a seasons table and an episode table. 
I create a series, then I create a season by selecting a series, and then I create episodes by first selecting a series and then the season. 
I am stuck in the episodes part. What I wanted was that when I select a seasons, only the series related to that series are in the drop down table. Can I get some assistance on how to tackle this issue.
Also, in my episodes table, I do have season_id and episode_id.
Here is my create blade for Episode:

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="card-title">
                Create Episode
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{route('episodes.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="series_id">Series</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="series_id">
                        @foreach ($series as $series)
                            <option value="{{$series->id}}">{{$series->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="season_id">Seasons</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="season_id">
                        @foreach ($seasons as $seasons)
                            <option value="{{$seasons->id}}">{{$seasons->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="about">About</label>
                    <textarea name="about" id="" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10">About</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subtitle">Subtitle</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtitle">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="serno">Serial Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serno">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subtitle">URL 1</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtitle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subtitle">URL 2</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtitle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subtitle">URL 3</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtitle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                    <label for="image">Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is the function for create:

```
public function create()
    {
        $seasons = Season::all();
        $series = Series::all();
        return view('admin.episodes.create', compact('seasons', 'series'));
    }
```

Now I want to do something with the series, where I select seasons from Season::all and then show series from the season I have selected.

EDIT:
Here is how my migrations look:

Series:

```
Schema::create('series', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('about');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Seasons:

```
Schema::create('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('series_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('subtitle');
            $table->string('about');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('serno');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Episodes:

```
Schema::create('episodes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('series_id');
            $table->integer('season_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('subtitle');
            $table->string('about');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('serno');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('url2');
            $table->string('url3');
            $table->string('medium');
            $table->string('medium2');
            $table->string('medium3');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: how your table looks like?

Comment: @ZeroOne I have updated the question to include my migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a series has multiple seasons. so you need a dependent drop-down for seasons while creating a new episode. you can use ajax request for loading dependent drop-down select data. when a series will be selected, a request will pass and seasons for that series will be returned.

so starting with the form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="series_id">Series</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="series_id" id="series_id">
        @foreach ($series as $series)
            <option value="{{$series->id}}">{{$series->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="season_id">Seasons</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="season_id" id="season_id">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

the script section

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('#series_id').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ route("getSeasons", ":id") }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', id);

        $('#season_id').find('option').not(':first').remove();
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(response){
               var len = 0;
               if(response != null){
                   len = response.length;
               }
               else {
                   alert('sorry, no seasons were found for this series');
               }
               if(len > 0){
                   for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                       var id = response[i].id;
                       var name = response[i].name;
                       var option = "<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>"; 
                       $("#season_id").append(option); 
                   }
               }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the route in the web.php file

```
Route::get('getseasons/{id}', 'YourController@getSeasons')->name('getSeasons');
```

and the controller code

```
public function getSeasons($id=0){
    $data = Season::where('series_id',$id)->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

feel free to ask anything you don't understand :)

Comment: Nice! one more thing, I already have a controller, how do I incorporate json response in it? I have mentioned the specific controller in my question above

Comment: what do you mean by incorporating json response in a controller??

Comment: i mean I already have a series variable which is being passed to the route using create function, wouldnt a second route mess that up?